# (convergence of series) Real Analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image]

I've understood the part until the underline. That is if series a(n) is convergent then a(n) when n tends to infinity equals 0. But do not seem to understand the underlined part. Is it true that for every convergent sequence there would be a number when a(n) <= 1. How does the limit value equalling 0 further imply to this point? Thank you.

Comment: Apply definition of limit. What does it mean to say $a_n \to 0$? (Take $\epsilon =1$ in the definition of limit).

Answer (score 2):

That’s by the definition of limit. The statement
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0
$$

is equivalent to saying that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $K$ such that
$$
|a_n -0|=|a_n| \le \varepsilon
$$
whenever $n\ge K$. In the text, the author is just taking $\varepsilon=1$.